# pass a function to QtConcurrent::map

Tags: c++, qt4, qtconcurrent

Here's my desired code:

```
class Machine {

private:
   QSet<State*> states;
   State* step(State* st){/*...*/}

public:
   void makeStep(){
        //...
        QTConcurrent::map(states, step);
        //...
   }
```

My problem: This doesn't compile, since `step()` is neither a global function nor a member of `State`. But logically this would be correct, because `step()`  does not modify a thing - it only accesses a structure of maps, but again, read-only.

What should to get modified, however, is the set `states`. I wanted to be smart and modify each `State*` concurrently (in a non-blocking fashion).

Should I make `step()` global?  Would it help?

Comment: I cant, since Im using a member of the object. Its what `step()` is about

Comment: As the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtconcurrentmap.html#using-bound-function-arguments) suggests, have you tried `std::bind(&Machine::step, this)` for the function?

Comment: I ended up binding `step()` to a function object. [Watch me struggle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647319/stdbind-this-and-qtconcurrent)