# std::bind, this and QtConcurrent

Tags: c++, c++11, qtconcurrent, stdbind

Im trying to use `std::bind` to bind `this` to method that is used in `QtConcurrent::blockingMapped`

Header:

```
class TuringMachine
{
private:
    TRTable table;
    std::set<ConfigNode*> currentConfigs;

    //function object
    std::function<std::set<ConfigNode*>( const TuringMachine*, ConfigNode*)> step_f;
    //method it will hold
    std::set<ConfigNode *> step(TuringMachine* this_m ,ConfigNode *parent);

    std::set<ConfigNode*>& makeStep();
```

}

Source:

```
    TuringMachine::TuringMachine(/**/)  
{

    step_f = std::bind(&TuringMachine::step, this, std::placeholders::_1);
}

std::set<ConfigNode*> &TuringMachine::makeStep(){

    auto configSet = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped<QLinkedList<std::set<ConfigNode*>>>(currentConfigs, step_f);//concurrent execution!

   /**/ 
   return currentConfigs;
}
std::set<ConfigNode*> TuringMachine::step(TuringMachine *this_m, ConfigNode * parent){     //the actual step
  /**/
}
```

So what Im doing here is running step conncurrently with `blockingMapped` on each `ConfigNode` in `currentConfigs`. Im using `std::bind` to bind `this` to `step` so it only requires one argument, as in the documentation of `blockingMapped`.

Im getting

```
error: no match for call to '(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<std::set<ConfigNode*> (TuringMachine::*)(TuringMachine*, ConfigNode*)>(TuringMachine*, std::_Placeholder<1>)>) (const TuringMachine*, ConfigNode*)'
.../Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore/qtconcurrentmapkernel.h:121: error: no match for call to '(std::function<std::set<ConfigNode*>(const TuringMachine*, ConfigNode*)>) (ConfigNode* const&)'
.../Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore/qtconcurrentmapkernel.h:136: error: no match for call to '(std::function<std::set<ConfigNode*>(const TuringMachine*, ConfigNode*)>) (ConfigNode* const&)'
```

And `note: 2 arguments expected, 1 provided`

Where did I go wrong?

**EDIT**

Corrected, working version (for future "reference"):

Header:

```
    //function object
    std::function<std::set<ConfigNode*>( ConfigNode*)> step_f;
    //method it will hold
    std::set<ConfigNode *> step(ConfigNode *parent);
```

Source:

```
    TuringMachine::TuringMachine(/**/)  
{
    step_f = std::bind(&TuringMachine::step, this, std::placeholders::_1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to bind a member function, you would have to pass a `this` pointer, which in your case would mean that you would have to pass 2 `this`-pointers:

Normal call to member function:

```
struct bar {
  int a;
  void foo() {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
  }

  void call_yourself() {
     auto f = std::bind(&bar::foo, this);
     f();
  }
};
```

Your case:

```
    step_f = std::bind(&TuringMachine::step, this, this,std::placeholders::_1);
```

Without understanding your code, I would probably redesing your code such that you can avoid the double `this` pointer.

Comment: Why is the second `this` required?

Comment: @Evgeni the first this is required to call a member function because when doing so, the second argument needs to be a pointer to a class from which your member function originates or an object of your class directly. You could for example also say `std::bind(&foo::bar, bar())`.

Comment: Well, what I'm basically trying is to run `step` concurrently on several `ConfigNode` objects. `blockingMapped` seemed a good idea, because it does just that. But I cant just use a member function, as seen [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtconcurrentmap.html#using-bound-function-arguments). I must bind it or make it static/global.

Comment: I eliminated the double this. Turns out I dont need to pass this to the method. Who knew :-P. Now its `step_f = bind(&TuringMachine::step, this, placeholders::_1);` and it works. Thanks